# Flash ROM of Samsung Tab A6 (SM-T585)

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, 8.0-oreo

I have Samsung Tab A6 (SM-T585) running Android 8.0 Oreo. It has a Knox application which limits a lot of features on my device. I need to get rid of it, flash a new ROM, and get everything back to normal.

I've already tried to go to "Download mode" by pressing (VOL Down + Power + Home) but it just boots normally (download mode is disabled somehow)

I've also searched for ADB solutions, but no luck yet.

How to flash ROM on Samsung Tab A6?

Comment: sure about device model? powered off device for sure? pressed and kept hold buttons in right order (power button last)? https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-t585-galaxy-tab-a-101-2016-lte/recovery-mode

Answer (score 0):

If download mode is disabled flash update.zip from recovery mode

Comment: **side note to visitors:** download mode can be disabled by [MDM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3775903) Software or other [methods](https://ge0n0sis.github.io/posts/2016/05/how-to-lock-the-samsung-download-mode-using-an-undocumented-feature-of-aboot)

Comment: can you explain more where can i get this update.zip file and what exact step should i do i have Samsung tablet A6

Comment: https://www.thecustomdroid.com/sideload-ota-update-stock-recovery-adb

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/download-samsung-stock-rom

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy